# Best approach to assigning existing data to a new django user

Tags: python, django

I am new in Django and I wanted to know what is the right approach to the following problem:

I have a table of companies, which is m2m with the table of users. Since they can be created by the users.
So what I want to do is, every time a user is created, I take a "default" company with a certain id and copy it to this new user.
This way the user will be able to make the changes he wants in this company without affecting the original one that is being copied.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```py
def create_default_company_for_user(user: User):
    create_kwargs = {}  # Whatever values you want for the new company fields
    default_company = Company.objects.create(**create_kwargs)
    user.company_set.add(default_company)
```

Call this where you create users. The best way would probably be to use it as a [Django's post_save signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#post-save) receiver:

```py
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_default_company_for_user(
    sender, user: User, created: bool, **kwargs
):
    if created:
        create_kwargs = {}  # Whatever values you want for the new company fields
        default_company = Company.objects.create(**create_kwargs)
        user.company_set.add(default_company)
```

Note: I haven't use a "default company to copy" what you want are default field values you can use to create new companies (in this case it's the `create_kwargs` variable, which should be a constant defined as a dictionary somewhere in your code)

Comment: Clepsyd! Thank you very much! that's exactly what I was looking for.
As a result of this question, I got another question.
What would be the way to do it if company has more tables associated. 
For example company, has its bills table associated to it with a foreign key and also has another table of employees and so on.
How would I do to "copy" all this and make it available for a new user, since it would not be only one table.
I think this is too long and maybe I should ask another question.

Comment: Yes another question would be better so that people can easily find it and potential answers. Make sure you to be as precise as you can, and give details and examples along with the question. Anything to make your train of though more explicit :)

Comment: Great, then that's what I'll do. Thank you very much again.